# What to do to make '_Generic('a', char : 1, int : 2) == 1' true

Tags: c, generics, c11

Is there any way the compiler can set the type `'a'` to `char`, instead of `int`.
This makes the values of these expressions true:

```c
sizeof('a') == 1

_Generic('a', char : true, default : false)
```

In gcc `_Generic('a', char : true, default : false) == false`

Comment: You can't in C11. It's standard C that defines the type of character constants as int. I don't know if the latest C23 changes that, but it's highly unlikely that it does.

Comment: Even if you could do this, it would be a compatibility and debugging nightmare. You don't want to end up debugging weird heap corruption issues because a macro expansion in some library header file you've never heard of got an unexpected value of `sizeof('\0')` and ended up computing a wrong buffer size to allocate or something like that.

Comment: If you try to turn C into your own personal not-quite-C variant, you're going to end up subtly incompatible with existing code written for *actual* C. It's nowhere near worth it.

Comment: `_Generic(*"a", char : true, default : false)` will be true, if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that character constants in C are `int`, not `char`. This is a well-known flaw of the C language. One easy solution to the problem might be to compile a specific file as C++, then link the generated .o file with the rest of the C project.

Otherwise you'd have to invent your own custom notation through some mysterious macro, which is really NOT recommended. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CH(c) (#c [0])

int main (void)
{
  printf("%c %zu\n", CH(a), sizeof(CH(a)) );
}
```

Similarly, `"a"[0]` or `*"a"` will give the letter `a` of type `char` with size 1.

This will still allow hex escape sequences and the like, such as `CH(\x61)` to print `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(char)'a'` instead of `a`.

```c
sizeof( (char)'a' )   // 1
```

```c
_Generic( (char)'a', char : true, default : false )  // true
```

Comment: No, the effect I want to achieve is to have all `'a'` have `(char)'a'` effect.

Comment: Then replace all `'a'` with `(char)'a'`. My answer stands.